# How to add a bind list to the TryUpdateModel in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I have the following action method:-

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        Assessment a = elearningrepository.GetAssessment(id);

        try
        {
            if (TryUpdateModel(a))
            {
                elearningrepository.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = a.AssessmentID });
            }
        }
//code does here
```

but I can not write something like  `if (TryUpdateModel(a, "Assessment", new string { "Date"}))` to specify that I only allow the Date property to be updated.
**So how I can add a bind list to the above** `if (TryUpdateModel(a))`?

BR

Answer (score 0):

> but I can not write something like
>
> `if (TryUpdateModel(a, "Assessment", new string { "Date"}))`

That's because you should write it like this, since the allowed properties argument represents a string array:

```
if (TryUpdateModel(a, "Assessment", new[] { "Date" }))
{

}
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply, but using ur code the update will never be performed ,, even if i try to update the date field it will not be saved and the old value will still be there. baring in mind that the other fields in the edit view are disabled so they should not be part of the model binding

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you stay away from using TryUpdateModel in general.

The repository usually has an update method that sets the entityState to modified before Save() is called, i cannot see that in the code above.

If your goal is to display a record and only allow date to be saved, then create a view for that model, and render fields with:

This sets the model for the view:

```
@model YourNamespace.Models.Assessment
```

`@Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.propertyToDisplay)`

on the items you only want to display, and a

```
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Date)
```

In your action controller you take the properties you want to bind to as input parameters:

**Edited**

```
    class Assessment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    //Other properties
}

public ActionResult Edit(int Id, DateTime Date)
{
    var assessment = elearningrepository.GetAssessment(id); 

    assessment.Date = Date;

    elearningrepository.UpdateAssessment(assessment);
    elearningrepository.Save();

    //Redirect to action Detail
}
```

In this case the model binder should just bind to Id, and Date, so even if someone tries to post other values (editing the html form is easy), parameters in ActionResult should be named exactly as in the Model and use that to fetch and update the entity.

You should validate that the user actually can access and edit that id, or as an alternative use [MVC Security Codeplex](http://mvcsecurity.codeplex.com/) to check that the Id parameter has not been tampered with. it is really easy and convenient to use, but that is another discussion.

As an alternative you can use an attribute like this, described in [this blog](http://ittecture.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/tip-of-the-day-199-asp-net-mvc-defining-model-binding-explicitly/), but I don't use that myself:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create( [Bind(Include="Id,Date")] Assessment assessment)
```

Comment: ok thanks for ur reply, but as part of the MVC web application security i should avoid over posting thread; that why i need to specify a white list using the [bind]. i need this approach all over my application and not for this specific case only. any suggestion...

Comment: I edited the post quite a bit. In the suggested solution, only the properties you want from the view is bound. If you really do not want to post anything but the values you need, you need to put only what you would like to post inside @using Html.BeginForm (which creates the form tags) - in this case only Date and Id, or you need to post to the action method using jQuery.post or Javascript.

Comment: thanks for ur edit , but this method will not scale well for me, since in other senarios i might need the white list to include more than just single Date field. BR

Answer (score -1):

i tried this an it works fine

```
 string[] allowedProperties = new[] { "Date" }; 
            try 
            { 
                if (TryUpdateModel(a, allowedProperties))  
                {
```